# Formula for finding maximum/minimum area from rounded x and y values?

Tags: area, boundary-value-problem

I have a problem from the GCSE revision book I'm using. They don't expect students at this level to calculate the maximum/minimum range (bounds?) from rounded x and y values.

> A floor is being measured as being 5.3m x 4.2m to the nearest 10cm (0.1m). This gives an area of 22.26 square metres. The real values of x and y could be 5.25-5.35m and 4.15-4.25m. Maximum floor area is 22.7375 square metres and 21.7875 square metres.

I understand all this and the terminology used perfectly. But the book doesn't give a specific formula for calculating the highest/lowest extremes.

Perhaps I'm over-complicating. Perhaps I am just expected to multiply minimum-x by minimum y for the minimum extreme, and do the same with the maximum for the maximum. Am I missing something? Is there a formula at this GCSE level to calculate this? Or do I need to wait for A-level level (or higher) to find a more complex formula?

Thanks a lot in advance. And excuse me if I'm making a glaring error and missing the forest for the trees. I've been spending a week reviewing my GCSE mathematics and I'm still refreshing everything I did in school. Some things are going right over my head these first few days.

Comment: No formula is required. This is a matter of understanding that multiplying by a bigger number yields a bigger number.

Comment: Were these max and min given as answers? They are obtained, as you thought, by multiplying the max possible length and width, and the min possible length and width..

Comment: @André Nicolas
Yes, all those values are given in the book. It's a completed example calculation. I'm just picking it apart to understand the process better. It says: "the safest method is to work out the answer using all four combinations and see which combinations give the maximum and minimum results."

That sounds fine, although a bit of a long, brute force kind of way to get the maximum/minimum bounds.

Perhaps I will get to this in A-level math soon, but am I right in thinking that you can "add" and "multiply" ± values?

Comment: You don't need all four combinations, as pointed out by Matt Samuel. The biggest possible area is obtained by multiplying the biggest possible length by the biggest possible width. A similar remark applies to smallest possible area. Thus there are two computations to do, not four.

Comment: @André Nicolas
Yes that's logical. The other two calculations are redundant. The book skips information I should have on one page, then over-simplifies on the next page. This page seems to be oversimplifying it too much. Thanks for your input in any case.